# styleClass property not working in themes for InputField.EditBox

Tags: xpages

I am trying to set the font and size of edit boxes via themes.

If I do something like:

```
<control>
    <name>InputField.EditBox</name>
    <property>
        <name>style</name>
        <value>
            font-family: Trebuchet MS, arial, verdana, ms sans serif;
            font-size: 50pt;            
        </value>
    </property>
</control>
```

then it works great but if I try using the styleClass property and reference a CSS class the theme seems to be ignored.   I have a similar issue with Column.View and InputField.TextArea  but a number of other controls work just fine with styleClass and css.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following adds a CSS class to all edit boxes:

```
<control>
    <name>InputField.EditBox</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>testClass</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Remember to include the related style sheet on the XPage using either the standard `xp:this.resources` option or by using the theme option. In a theme the following includes a style sheet on all XPages:

```
<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>custom.css</href>
</resource>
```

The style sheet class looks like this using your example:

```
.testClass {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, arial, verdana, ms sans serif;
    font-size: 50pt;
}
```

Comment: Still not working for me.  But I found out why.  I created a mini example using your sample code.  If I extend webstandard in my theme then your sample works but if I extend onui then it does not work.  Any idea why?

Comment: It works with oneui and oneuiv2. It also works with oneuiv2.1 BUT the oneuiv2.1 CSS has a more specific class selector (.lotusui button, .lotusui input, .lotusui select) that overrides the .testClass CSS class. If you use the class selector ".lotusui .testClass" in your CSS it works. This is not a XPages/themes issue but rather a CSS issue.